# jQuery - How to set a div to a specific pixel height and then animate to percentage - smoothly?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that needs to be set at a specific pixel height, say 100px, and then when a "show more" div is clicked, up that div up to 100% of its natural height. The trick is to make it happen SMOOTHLY.

I can animate it smoothly if I go from one fixed height, say 100px, to another fixed height, say 200px, but that doesn't work for me.

Is there a way to open a div at a specific height and have it animate (slide down)  smoothly to a percentage?

Here's the jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EvikJames/3pCSg/2/

```
<div class="Model">
    Some info. Some info. Some info.
    Some info. Some info. Some info.
    Some info. Some info. Some info.
</div>
<div class="ShowMore ">show more</div>

.Model {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
   .ShowMore {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

$(".Model").each(function() {
    $(this).css("height", "50px");
});

$(".ShowMore").click(function() {
    // this works smoothly
    // $(this).prev().css("height", "100px");
});
$(".ShowMore").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().animate({height: "100%"}, 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can grab the height of the element before setting it and animating to that:

```
var m = $(".Model").height();

...

$(".ShowMore").click(function() {
    $(this).prev().animate({
        height: m + "px"
    }, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MzWGz/

Comment: Awesome answer. I had not thought of that.  Your solution was EXACTLY what I wanted.  Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just put the show more content in it's own div and hide and show that instead, then you can just make the top level div height auto:

```
<div style="height:auto">
  <p>Always show</p>
  <div class="OtherContent">
     ...Other Content
  </div>
  <div class="ShowMore>Show More</div>
</div>


$(".ShowMore").click(function() {
// this works smoothly
  $(this).prev().slideDown();
});
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Wvb6w/

Comment: First, my code DOES have the show more link it its own div, just like yours. Second, I need it to open at a specific height, like I said. It has to start at 50px and open to 100%.  Thanks though!